# Creating identity column in excel without using formulas

Tags: excel, sql-server-2005

I am using an excel spreadsheet as a way to manually format data for import into SQL2005. My issue is that in the DB I have an identity column so when I add rows to the XLS sheet I have to manually create the identity column since using formulas would end up exporting the formula to SQL2005 instead of the number is represents. Does anyone know a quick macro I could use to insert incremental numbers into a column?

Comment: if you set an identity field in SQL2005 to auto increment you don't need to include anything in the excel sheet, unless you need to reference them before importing them. And are you sure the formulas import if you use one? My experience has been the result imports.

Comment: You are right the formulas do not import. Thanks

Comment: @Josh Did you ever find a solution to this problem?

Answer (score 0):

A more efficient way than using a loop is as follows. (Assume your identity column is A)

```
Dim r As Range

Sheet1.Range("A1").FormulaR1C1 = "1"
Sheet1.Range("A2").FormulaR1C1 = "2"

Set r = Sheet1.Range("A1", Sheet1.Range("A" & Sheet1.UsedRange.Rows.Count))
Sheet1.Range("A1:A2").AutoFill Destination:= r
```

Answer (score -1):

This little loop will do it.

It will put on Col A unique numbers so they can be used in your ID field
when going to SQL server.

Sub Increment_Numbers()

Dim i As Long

```
For i = 1 To 100

    Range("A1").Offset(i).Value = i

Next i
```

End Sub